# Curl/Debian Could not resolve Host intermittent errors

Tags: php, node.js, curl, dns

I have production scripts performing diverse calls to diverse urls in PHP (curl) or http requests via nodejs such as:

- A few hundreds NodeJS requests a day to my own server at OVH (`mydomain.com/api/...`)
- Same thing with PHP (Symfony2) in Curl to an external API (`view-api.box.com`), approx 100 a day (well under my API rate limit)
- Same thing with an old server of my website on another hosted domain of my own for synchronizations at OVH (`myolddomain.fr`) each time a user logs in
- A few calls to an external website to update some documents (`http://ec.europa.eu/blahblah...`)

Theses requests worked well for about 2 years and it has started to give me the following errors last two weeks:

**NodeJs errors**

`getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` for `mydomain.com/api/...`

**Php curl errors**

`Could not resolve host: view-api.box.com` or `Curl err[6]: Could not resolve host: myolddomain.fr`.

I haven't change or updgraded any package on my debian server (`Debian GNU/Linux 8`) and the problems started **intermittently recently** and seem to be really random (*5 to 10 times a day* maybe)

I suspect it has nothing to do with the code but some DNS issues or trouble finding any remote domain (even my own) but i have not idea where to look since it comes from separate code/requests...

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
domain local
search local
nameserver 213.186.33.99 # (OVH Dns servers)
```

The question is... where should i look first to solve this? Any hints out there?